# IllegalArgumentException on sendTextMessage after change to support dual SIM

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, smsmanager

I used this code to send SMS messages, and everything worked just fine.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, body, sentPI, null);
```

Since few days ago I changed my code to support dual SIM phones, I added a field in my settings screen, check for permissions, all that and I tested it on couple of my phones (+emulator even it doesn't have dual SIM, but just to see if it will work fine) and everything worked fine. After publishing I keep getting `IAException` from sendTextMessage. Number and body arguments are provided when user clicks on card from recyclerview, and not single line of code was changed there. Only my sendTXT method. Here is the new code:

```
final boolean yesReadPhoneState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
//sim is int and can be 0, 1, 2 - 0 for single sim and 1,2 for dual
try {
            //dual SIM
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && dualSIM && sim != 0 && yesReadPhoneState) {
                SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);
                if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
                    List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

                    SubscriptionInfo simInfo1 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
                    SubscriptionInfo simInfo2 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(1);

                    if (sim == 1) {
                        SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo1.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(number, null, body, sentPI, null);
                    }
                    else if (sim == 2) {
                        SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo2.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(number, null, body, sentPI, null);
                    }
                }
                //single SIM if dualSIM is on but still is single sim
                else {
                    sim = 0;
                    dualSIM = false;
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, body, sentPI, null);
                }
            }
            //single SIM
            else {
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, body, sentPI, null);
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {...
```

Oh, one more thing I forgot to mention, I also made custom `dialog`, instead of generic one,  to show 2 additional `radio buttons` for checking sim1 or sim2. Dialog method takes number and body as arguments, and alongside them passes int sim, something like this:

```
private void customDialog(final String number, final String body) {
...
.setPositiveButton(...
    sendSMS(number, body, sim)...
```

And this is stack trace I get from play console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal (SmsManager.java:367)
  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage (SmsManager.java:350)
  at rs.dreamlight.parkomat.MainActivity.a (MainActivity.java:75)
  at rs.dreamlight.parkomat.MainActivity.access$000 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$102 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$1600 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$202 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$2102 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$2300 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$2600 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$2800 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$3200 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$3500 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$4002 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$502 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$702 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .cirlat (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .dialogObnova (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .dozvole (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .fontZoom (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .komparator (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .nijeIzabranGrad (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .posaljiSMS (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .posaljiSMSService (MainActivity.java)
  at rs.dreamlight.parkomat.MainActivity$14.onClick (MainActivity.java:57)
  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:37)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Looking at the source, it really seems like the only way `SmsManager` would throw specifically an `IllegalStateException` there is if either the number or the message body is empty. You should probably at least check for that right before making the `sendTextMessage()` calls.

Comment: Well that is the part I don't get. `Number` and `body` are taken from `recyclerview` card, which always have those args. If there is no card, `sendSMS` method can't be called. And I can't check because every time I tested it worked. So I have to guess which link of the `RVCard.onClick(getNumber, getBody) -> customDialog(passedtNumber, passedBody) -> sendSMS(passedNumber, passedBody)` chain is the problem.

Comment: Well, I can't really comment on the rest of your program flow, 'cause all we've got here is the send method, basically. And I know you already knew about the empty number/body issue (from your previous post). I'm just sayin' that it really seems like that's the main possibility here.